# Use Non-Generic Base Class Collection for Derived Class?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, collections

Well, it's hard to explain it in words. So here's an example. In the SDL .NET API, there's a class called `SpriteCollection` which is designed to be, well... a collection of sprites. However the problem is that for some reason the developers decided to not make `SpriteCollection` generic, like the .NET `List<>` class. So, I guess, it can only work with the `Sprite` class or other classes that inherit from `Sprite`? Anyway, let's say I derive `Tile` from `Sprite`. And I add two new properties to it:

```
class Tile : Sprite
{

    public Tile(char symbol = default(char), bool solid = true)
    {
        Symbol = symbol;
        Solid = solid;
    }

    public char Symbol
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool Solid
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now, how can I use the `SpriteCollection` with `Tile`s and still be able to use the `Tile` exclusive properties like `Solid`?

One (probably stupid) solution would perhaps be this:

```
Tile t = (Tile) myCollection[i];
if (t.Solid) { ... }
```

Is there any better way to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposal to cast the return values of the `SpriteCollection` to `Tile` is the way to do it. You do not have better options if you need to use the collection class provided and cannot change it.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to avoid casting as you iterate you way through, you could override the GetEnumerator method.

```
public class TileList: SpriteList {

    public new IEnumerator<Tile> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var tile in GetBase())
        {
            if (tile is Tile)
            {
                yield return tile as Tile;
            }
        }
    }

    protected SpriteList GetBase()
    {
        return (SpriteList )this;
    }
}
```

(This does of course cast, but it encapsulates that casting in the enumerator.)

Comment: You could just use LINQ's `OfType()` method which does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, how can I use the SpriteCollection with Tiles and still be able to use the Tile exclusive properties like Solid?

You can do this via a cast of some form.  Your method works, though I personally would use:

```
Tile t = myCollection[i] as Tile;
if (t != null)
{
    if (t.Solid) { ... }
}
```

This allows you to add your `Tile` instances, but also other sprites to the collection safely.

The same issue arises if you use a generic class, such as `List<Sprite>`.  This will allow you to use any `Sprite` subclass, not just `Tile`.  In order to have a type safe collection without casting, you'd have to use `List<Tile>`, which would restrict you to only tiles, not other sprites, within your collection.